# Change of variable in a PDE led to a change of the sign of some terms

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm studying this equation and trying to understand why the signs of all the terms changed (except for the sign of the first term). I think it has to do with the chain rule but I cannot understand how exactly it works here.

[image: image: pde change of variable]

Comment: In fact, only the sign of the first term changed (due to the chain rule). Then, the expression was rewritten (multiply by (-1)).

Comment: Ok tell me if this is right. The first term in the initial equation is dv/dt, and this term is equal to du/dt because v(t,-)=u(tau,-). For the chain rule we have du/dt = du/dtau * dtau/dt = - du/dtau, because dtau/dt = (T-t)/dt = -1 ?

Comment: Sound wave, See my ansewr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation has the form
$$av'(t,x)+bv_{xx}(t,x)+cv_x(t,x)-dv(t,x)+\lambda\int v(t,x+y)f(y)dy=0,\quad \forall\ t$$
where $'$ stands for the derivative with respect to the first variable.
In particular,
$$av'(T-\tau,x)+bv_{xx}(T-\tau,x)+cv_x(T-\tau,x)\\-dv(T-\tau,x)+\lambda\int v(T-\tau,x+y)f(y)dy=0,\quad \forall\ \tau\tag {$*$}$$

The function $u$ is defined by
$$u(\tau,x)=v(T-\tau,x).\tag{1}$$

Then:
$$u'(\tau,x)=-v'(T-\tau,x)\tag{2}$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $x$:
$$u_x(\tau,x)=v_x(T-\tau,x),\qquad u_{xx}(\tau,x)=v_{xx}(T-\tau,x).\tag{3}$$

Thus, Substituting $(1),(2),(3)$ into $(*)$,
$$-au'(\tau,x)+bu_{xx}(\tau,x)+cu_x(\tau,x)-du(\tau,x)+\lambda\int u(\tau,x+y)f(y)dy=0,\quad \forall\ \tau$$

Multiplying by $-1$:

$$au'(\tau,x)-bu_{xx}(\tau,x)-cu_x(\tau,x)+du(\tau,x)-\lambda\int u(\tau,x+y)f(y)dy=0,\quad \forall\ \tau$$

which gives the second equation after a change of variables in the integral.

Comment: Ok thanks Pedro, but why u'=-v' ?

Comment: @soundwave According to the chain rule, if $u(\tau)=f(g(\tau))$ then $u'(\tau)=f'(g(\tau))g'(\tau)$. Apply this for $f(\tau)=v(\tau,x)$ and $g(\tau)=T-\tau$.